# Bigquery api response show in the json f, v format. But I need column header

Tags: google-bigquery

**Sample response -**
Instead of v , I need column name, response from big query api .

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be referencing the low-level JSON field value (f,v) syntax of `tabledata.list` and `jobs.getQueryResults` API responses.

Generally, the thing you do is decode this using the schema which you have captured prior to processing rows.  However, it's not clear why you're working with this at all; libraries exist in multiple languages that handle this on your behalf.  More information can be found in the BigQuery reference documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries

Is there a reason you're attempting to do the decoding yourself?